# Getting a FileSystemException when reading text file

Tags: exception, filesystems, dart

I'm trying to read a text file in Dart as a command line application:

```
void readFile(){
  var file = new File('data.txt');
  file.readAsLines(encoding: ASCII).then((lines) {
    print(lines);
  }).catchError(print);
}
```

I keep getting this error:

```
FileSystemException: Failed to decode data using encoding 'us-ascii', path = data.txt
```

Changing to UTF8 yields a similar error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This probably means that your file contains binary data that is not valid ASCII or UTF-8.

You can try LATIN1 and see if that works for you. It is guaranteed not to yield an error (since every byte is directly mapped to a character) but characters outside the ASCII range might look different than what you expected them to be.